# How do I generate UUID in PHPcassa

Tags: cassandra, uuid, phpcassa

I have been searching google and stackoverflow for a tutorial on generating UUID using PHPcassa.  I am a noob and I cant seem to figure this out.  I am using the latest PHPcassa version, which is this URL http://thobbs.github.com/phpcassa/

can anyone give me a step by step example on how to generate one?

Thank you very much ！！！！

Answer (score 1):

There's a UUID class in the phpcassa library that you can use.  For example:

```
use phpcassa\UUID;
...
$my_uuid = UUID::uuid1();
```

You may also want to look at [these examples](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa/blob/master/examples/alternate_formats.php) if you have a UUID comparator.